# Convert the polar equation to Cartesian coordinates : $r^3 = − 7cos\theta$

Tags: polar-coordinates

I have a question to convert $r^3 = − 7cos\theta$ into cartesian coordinates.

I'm having a hard time understanding what to do.  I'm familiar with converting a polar coordinate to a Cartesian coordinate (say you're given $(\frac{\pi}{4}, 3)$ and asked to convert to Cartesian coordinates) but I'm not sure what to do with an actual equation.

Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Do you know the general formula for converting cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ to polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$? As a hint, you have $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. Then plug this into your equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying both sides by $r$, we obtain:
\begin{align*}
r^4 &= -7r\cos\theta \\
(r^2)^2 &= -7(r \cos\theta) \\
(x^2 + y^2)^2 &= -7x
\end{align*}

Comment: That makes sense, but how is that a "coordinate"?  I was thinking they wanted something in the form of $(x, y)$.

Comment: I guess the question was a bit imprecise; they likely meant to say: "Convert the given polar equation into a Cartesian equation."

Comment: Ok cool, thanks.  Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.